how to sort array of nested objects by the objects name?
I have this multidimensional object from an API:
let curr = {
    "base_currency_code": "EUR",
    "base_currency_name": "Euro",
    "amount": "10.0000",
    "updated_date": "2024-04-14",
    "rates": {        
        "USD": {
            "currency_name": "United States dollar",
            "rate": "1.0649",
            "rate_for_amount": "10.6489"
        },
        "AUD": {
            "currency_name": "Australian dollar",
            "rate": "1.6444",
            "rate_for_amount": "16.4443"
        },
        "CAD": {
            "currency_name": "Canadian dollar",
            "rate": "1.4669",
            "rate_for_amount": "14.6690"
        }
    },
    "status": "success"
}

And I want a sorted array of objects like this :
let curr = [
    {
        "id": "AUD",
        "currency_name": "Australian dollar",
        "rate": "1.6444",
        "rate_for_amount": "16.4443"
    },
    {
        "id": "CAD",
        "currency_name": "Canadian dollar",
        "rate": "1.4669",
        "rate_for_amount": "14.6690"
    },
    {
        "id": "USD",
        "currency_name": "United States dollar",
        "rate": "1.0649",
        "rate_for_amount": "10.6489"
    }
]

The goal would be to adapt it for a Flatlist in react-native.
Been trying many tricks but nothing works. Any suggestions?

The result you are facing is not valid. There is no such thing like associative arrays in JavaScript

On a first step you can map the array to the array you need
const result = [];
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(curr.rates))
{
   const d = {
      id : key,
      currency_name : …
   };
   result.push(d);
});

And then simply sort by id
result.sort((a, b) => a.id.localCompare(b.id));

AUTHOR EDIT:
result.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);


btw if you know why, using your code, it works fine but when I try to add to const d
symbol: customCurr[key].symbol_native,
when customCurr is another json object with the same id's, it says " cannot read property symbol_native of undefined"
And its working fine if I put customCurr["USD"].symbol_native. Is this a problem of the key definition? I am lost with this
